# HTTP/JSON request formatting from Node-Red to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, httprequest, node-red

I'm having a hard time figuring out if my HTTP request from node-red to Google cloud is formatted correctly. I have a very simple function in Google cloud functions set up, just to check what is inbound and if everything is being passed on correctly. I pass it a couple of JSON data fields and return a random one just to test.

```
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res)
{
  var myResponse = req.body.topic;
  if(req.get('content-type') === "application/json")
  {
    myResponse += " - Json";
  }


  res.status(200).send(myResponse);
};
```

I read the JSON data in two ways here. The server responds with the string: "undefined - Json", which means it does not read *req.body.topic* correctly. As far as I understand, gcloud will parse the data in the body of the http request based on the *content-type* header. This parameter is obviously read correctly, but the rest is not.

In node red I pass the following data to the HTTP request node. I have my data fields as an object attached to the body field in the HTTP request.

```
{
   "url":"http://localhost:8010/my-smart-home-xxxx/us-central1/helloWorld",
   "body":
      {
         "topic":"smartGarden/001/moistureLevel",
         "payload":"11",
         "origin":"node-red-local"
       },
    "headers":
      {
        "content-type":"application/json"
      },
        "_msgid":"2aa44dc.b7391b2"
}
```

I'm a bit new to this so I'm probably making a very basic mistake.

I appreciate the help!

(I am currently running the gcloud functions emulator, but I had the same results in the actual cloud environment.)

Answer (score 0):

Normal practice on receiving input and verifying that the `content-type` is `json` is to run something like `JSON.parse()` to convert it from a string to json.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This however doesn't work?  I get the same problem whether or not I use the JSON.parse() function.